consul service mesh sidecar proxy - how to globally configure it?
In the configuration of Consul service mesh sidecar proxies, I have an example (serviceA.json):
{
  "service": {
    "name": "serviceA",
    "port": 8001,
    "connect": {
      "sidecar_service": {
        "proxy": {
          "upstreams": [
            {
              "destination_name": "serviceB",
              "local_bind_port": 9001
            },
            {
              "destination_name": "serviceC",
              "local_bind_port": 9003
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "check": {
      "http": "http://localhost:8001/health",
      "interval": "10s"
    }
  }
}

This configuration file indicates that the service serviceA listens on port 8001, and it needs to access serviceB through the sidecar proxy on port 9001, and access serviceC through the sidecar proxy on port 9003. However, if I have many services, writing the upstreams configuration in each service would be cumbersome. Is there a way to configure a global sidecar proxy ports so that it applies to each service?
I tried to add this proxy-defaults.json file to consul.d(the consul config dir):
{
  "Kind": "proxy-defaults",
  "Name": "global",
  "Config": {
    "Proxy": {
      "Config": {
        "local_service_address": "127.0.0.1",
        "upstreams": [
          {
            "destination_name": "serviceA",
            "local_bind_port": 9001
          },
          {
            "destination_name": "serviceC",
            "local_bind_port": 9003
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}

and run command:
consul config write proxy-defaults.json
but serviceA still can't request serviceC through sidecar proxy...
